# Groff renders brackets and square roots incorrectly

Tags: groff

The groff source

```
.EQ
left ( sqrt {1 over 2} right )
.EN
```

produces this

[image: expression]

when a PDF is made, and viewed with some PDF readers. (Here, Atril.)

The error occurs with large round brackets and/or square root signs.

However, if PostScript is used instead, then the expression is rendered properly.

[image: expression_2]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is to do with some PDF readers not knowing where the font is.

Four solutions:

1. Add `-P-yU` as an option to `groff`, e.g.

   ```
   groff -Tpdf -P-yU -e -me main.me > main.pdf
   ```
2. Add `-P-e` to embed the font, e.g.

   ```
   groff -Tpdf -P-e -e -me main.me > main.pdf
   ```
3. You could instead use the `-Tdvi` option and then compile a pdf using `dvipdf` to make the equations (and the whole document) become formatted in TeX style.

   ```
   groff -Tdvi -e -me main.me > main.dvi; dvipdf main.dvi
   ```
4. Use a PDF reader that displays them correctly anyway, e.g. ghostview or the Chromium browser.